# Why would there be no debug output when testing my Firefox Addon on mobile using cfx?

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, fennec

I am developing a Firefox addon and would like to test it on Android. I have downloaded Nightly on the phone and have root access.

Inside of the addon's directory, I run the following command:

```
cfx run -a fennec-on-device -b /bin/adb --mobile-app fennec --force-mobile
```

as according to the [documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/mobile.html).

`Nightly` is then opened up on my phone and I get the following output at the terminal:

```
Launching mobile application with intent name org.mozilla.fennec
Pushing the addon to your device
Starting: Intent { act=android.activity.MAIN cmp=org.mozilla.fennec/.App (has extras) }
```

But there is no debug output whatsoever. I have tried putting `console.log` statements at the top of my `main.js` and the first content script that is supposed to load.

Is this a common problem? What else can I check? If more specific information is necessary, please post a comment.

Comment: Does it work if you run it with `--mobile-app firefox` instead? What about doing an `adb logcat`? Anything suspicious there?

Comment: @nmaier I tried `adb logcat` and I got a lot of `D/ConnectivityService( 1327): getMobileDataEnabled returning false`. I don't know what to look for as I am new to android development.

Comment: Okay, finally got `--mobile-app firefox` to work and got this output: `error: my_project: An exception occurred.` I guess that counts as debug output, although it leaves much to be desired :)

Comment: My guess is that the SDK is not compatible with Firefox Android anymore. You could ask at their [IRC channel](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Jetpack) or [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Add-on%20SDK&component=Documentation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realise this question is almost a year old but I was having similar issues until I found a Mozilla Bugzilla issue reporting that cfx test wasn't showing results without "-v" (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=773028)

I added "-v" to my "cfx run", making it:

```
cfx run -v -a fennec-on-device -b "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" --mobile-app fennec --force-mobile
```

..and suddenly I actually get some info beyond "Starting: Intent"...

`Running cfx for attached Android device...
Launching mobile application with intent name org.mozilla.fennec
Pushing the addon to your device
Starting: Intent { act=android.activity.MAIN cmp=org.mozilla.fennec/.App (has extras) }
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
Could not read chrome manifest 'file:///data/data/org.mozilla.fennec/chrome.manifest'.
OpenGL compositor Initialized Succesfully.
Version: OpenGL ES 2.0
Vendor: ARM
Renderer: Mali-400 MP
FBO Texture Target: TEXTURE_2D
Adding HealthReport:RequestSnapshot observer.
Sending snapshot message.
main.js starting
console.log: tldr: main.js starting
....`

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround to get debug output by wrapping my entire `main.js` in a `try`/`catch` block like so:

```
try {
  var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

  pageMod.PageMod({/* etc */});

  // etc.

}
catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

I then test my app using `--mobile-app firefox` instead of `--mobile-app fennec` as @nmaier suggested in a comment.